# Apache Druid can store null value for number

Tags: druid

I write spec to collect data from kafka.
But I know that Druid will auto convert null value of type double, long to 0.0 and 0. '
But I want to store null value instead of 0.
So what should I do when set type for each dimension column.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my interpretation of the docs, it seems druid.generic.useDefaultValueForNull=false could help here, although it seems like this is an all or nothing (affects all columns) and also may have some performance implications: see [docs](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html#:%7E:text=NULL%20values&text=In%20the%20default%20value%20mode,has%20partial%20support%20for%20NULLs.) and this [blog](https://imply.io/blog/numeric-column-null-checks-apache-druid/). In the ingestion spec docs I could not find anything of that could suggest you can have a per column null handling setting. Just a thought but I am not sure of the order of operations during ingestion if this would do anything, but may be worth a POC: combine changing the above property to false with transformations, where you can transform the fields you want to keep for the default value first using nvl. I am not sure if that would work and what other implications it may have.

Answer (score 0):

`druid.generic.useDefaultValueForNull=false` is actually a system property and has to be added in following config file that will not convert `null` to 0. By default `druid.generic.useDefaultValueForNull=true`, and that is why the issue.

```
conf/druid/cluster/_common/common.runtime.properties
```

I must say, documentation is little bit vague though.