# Ingest null value for INT and LONG type column in Druid

Tags: druid

I am ingesting some data from JSON to Druid. The input data has null value for some of the INT and LONG fields. I want to store them as **null**, instead of storing them as 0. I am not able to figure out how to do that. Can anyone guide me through?

There is a similar question - [Apache Druid can store null value for number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71480544/apache-druid-can-store-null-value-for-number). The answers say it can be done, but it's not clear how it can be done.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Update-

`druid.generic.useDefaultValueForNull=false` is actually a system property and has to be added in following config file that will not convert `null` to 0. By default `druid.generic.useDefaultValueForNull=true`, and that is why the issue.

```
conf/druid/cluster/_common/common.runtime.properties
```

I must say, documentation is little bit vague though.